# iAd banner Not showing up in app store but is showing up in simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, iad

I recently updated my iPhone app with iAds. In the simulator, the iAds showed up and were working perfectly fine. My app was updated on May 15th, and I downloaded the app on my iPad after to see if the iAds were working. I didn't see them show up.

After looking at similar questions, I waiting for a couple of days to see if it would change. As of today, the iAds still haven't shown up on my iPad, but on iTunes Connect, it actually shows that my app has a total of 110 requests from May 19th to May 23rd, which makes no sense to me. How can I be getting requests if the iAds don't even show up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The banner will be blank if there aren't any ads currently available to show. This can happen for a number of reasons. The simulator simply shows an example ad for development purposes.

Have you followed the best practice of hiding the banner when no ad is available? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2264/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011827-CH1-HIDE_BLANK_OR_EMPTY_BANNERS

Comment: I looked at another question that said that if the app isn't universal, the iAds won't show up. How do I make my app universal because I don't think it is.

Comment: That's beyond the scope of this question. And not needed AFAIK.

Comment: What do you mean "beyond the scope of this question?" My question was why iAds weren't showing up, and if making the app universal will solve it, I think it's useful.